# Jump in ARM thumb code (Veneers?)

Tags: android, arm, vulkan, thumb

I'm disassembling Vulkan code from Android device

```
00009ddc <vkGetDeviceQueue>:
9ddc:   f000 b800   b.w 9de0 <vkGetDeviceQueue+0x4>
9de0:   e92d 43f0   stmdb   sp!, {r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, r9, lr}
9de4:   b089        sub sp, #36 ; 0x24
```

Anyone knows why the first instruction just jumps to next one (with 32-bit instruction .w)?

Comment: would probably need to see more code is this compiled?  is this a tail optimization of one function calling another?

Comment: I'd say it's a point to hook execution (for debugging/dynamically modifying the behavior of the program) by writing a different destination to the branch instruction.

Comment: Is that code from libvulkan.so, or from the device-specific Vulkan driver (e.g. vulkan.msm8996.so on Pixel)? On my local build of Android, libvulkan.so's vkGetDeviceQueue is just "ldr.w ip, [r0]; ldr.w ip, [ip, #8]; bx ip;" (sorry, can't do multi-line code blocks in a comment).